# Python lambda return value

Tags: python, lambda

I'm learning the lambda options to return in python and i have a question:

I need to fill the returns in this function:

```
def func(n):
   if n==0:
      print("finished")
   else:
      return ___
func(5)()()()()()
func(3)()()()
func(8)()()()()()()()()
```

The output:

```
finished
finished
finished
```

I thought this one is a recursive call like return func(n-1) but it doesn't work, and throws an error.
Is there an option to overcome the extra empty brackets? count them? do something, because it should be runnable.

Thanks

Comment: You should ask about one question per post, each containing what you've tried and researched so far

Comment: Why are there empty parentheses in the first place? Are they part of some assignment or homework that you are doing?

Comment: () is the function call. These are python basics... If you have `def foo():...`, then foo is the function itself, and you can call it as foo(). And you can return a function from a function

Comment: Not homehwork, just questions that "should help you get better with lambda expressions"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about needing to use lambdas and func n-1, specifically

```
return lambda: func(n-1)
```

This returns a lambda that doesn't need any parameters passed in, to handle the brackets, and the return of the is the function being called with n-1, which in most calls you're making, is returning the next lambda function call

Answer (score 0):

The operator () is the function call.
So for example:

```
def foo():
   print('Foo executed')

def bar():
   # We return the foo FUNCTION itself, without calling it.
   return foo
```

In the above code, if you execute `foo()`, it'll print "Foo executed". But if you execute `bar()`, it will return `foo`, which is the function. So you can execute `bar()()`, where the first () is executing the function bar, returning foo, and then with the second (), you call the returned foo function.

Edit: When I typed it, you removed the what are those bunch of () because they are new to you... But I just leave it there maybe it'll help.

Comment: Yes I know how to "solve it" with another fuction, but I didn't know the syntax should be like Sayse wrote dotn here.
Thank you!